# Which style,lambda..should or expect..to, is preferred for testing expectations in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I have seen both styles used widely: #1 `lambda { raise "Boom" }.should raise_error` and #2 `expect { raise "Boom" }.to raise_error`. I like expect..to more as it reads better and hides the creation of the proc.

I looked at rspec code and it seems expect..to is [suggested](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/features/expectations/expect_error.feature), however I regularly come across libraries using lambda..should. Is expect..to newer and hence not "famous" yet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`expect` is used since rspec-2, previously `lambda` had to be used.

RSpec "officially" recommends to use `expect` and it is possible that they will decide to "obsolete" lambda syntax.

The lambda syntax is used in most of the libraries that started life in RSpec1 days. They just haven't yet migrated (and why would they if it is still supported).

So, do use `expect` instead of `lambda`.